# Unable to upload static resources to sandbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, sandbox, static-resources

i have a sandbox on salesforce and i am pushing code there to test.
i am also using some static resources which i have uploaded there.

But this morning, when i tried to edit a static resource, i am seeing this -

[image]

I am unable to access already added static resources or add new?
This happened before also and that time i had to create a new sandbox.
How can i fix this? Please help..

Comment: can you switch it to classic and try?

Comment: That worked. Any ideas on what can be the issue with lightening experience while doing the same thing?

Comment: There could be different issue, like if you are under a corporate firewall, bad internet connection, etc. Also better to try in different browser to check if its really a browser issue, or as Pranay mentioned to switch to classic.

Comment: Switching to classic for just uploading static resources works.
but otherwise it just comes like in the screenshot. tried from office, from home. so, no firewall issue. happening in chrome, firefox, safari..

Comment: @ghostCoder have you raised a case with SF? if not you should.

Comment: Not a problem in Classic, only Lightning.

You also have a problem on the developer forums.

Have you tried it in incognito or private modus?

You might have an extension interfering?