# No option to ask a question in https://developer.salesforce.com discussion forums

Tags: visualforce, developer

I am trying to ask a question on https://developer.salesforce.com Discussion Forum, but there is no link/button to ask a question there.

[image]

Please guide me as to where can i ask a question there...

Answer (score 5):

Before addressing your directly question. Why not ask your question here on the Salesforce StackExchange? The Official Salesforce Developer Forums and this site fill a similar role. The primary difference being that this site follows the StackExchange Q&A format (like StackOverflow) rather than being a free-for-all forum.

---

Assuming you are signed in, which you appear to be, there should be a box at the top that prompts:

> What would you like to know?

[image]

Type the subject of your question there. If there aren't any existing matches you can use the "Post Your Question" button.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel. I did post my question here first, but there hasn't been an answer there yet (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251515/unable-to-upload-static-resources-to-sandbox), thats why i was looking if i can get some answers there...

Comment: And no, i cannot see this box "What would you like to know?" I am signed in.
Any ideas if this is governed by some permissions or anything?

Comment: @ghostCoder Are you seeing anything else in the area where I showed the prompt? I think there was recently an error message appearing there that they were working on fixing.

Comment: No, just seeing what i posted in the screenshot in the question. no error message there :( tried making another  user and accessing then. same issue, unable to see the search box visible in your screenshot.